# How to setup VS Code for Building, Running and Debugging simple C++ files in OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

The closest similar answer I found for it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377981/vs-code-setup-for-c)

But that doesn't contain an answer to my question. I also went through the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) for trying to have C++ support to VSCode. I didn't find OSX specific settings and I am not well versed with such configurations. Could someone please help
?

**Update:**

Adding the contents of tasks.json, launch.json, c_cpp_properties.json, and terminal output for more clarity:

tasks.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "build & debug file",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "g++",
    "args": [
      "-g",
      "-o",
      "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "${file}"
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "build & run file",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "g++",
    "args": [
      "-o",
      "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "${file}"
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
  }
]
```

}

launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    }
]
```

}

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0",
            "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4 }
```

Current problem I am facing with this configuration is that I get the following error when I try: Terminal-> Run Build Task-> build & debug file:

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xyz/Workspace/VSCode/.vscode/tasks.json, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7B 0x0A 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x22 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x22 0x3A ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/xyz/Workspace/VSCode/.vscode/tasks.json
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: You should first be able to build from command line, using 'any editor'. If you have this, show your build process (edit the question). If not, start with that before tackling VS Code (or any "non-IDE" programmers editor) integration.

Comment: @hyde I am able to build Cpp code from other editors such as Sublime Text and also debug them using CodeLite IDE. But it appears that we need to setup configs for the same in VSCode, specifically in the tasks.json, c_cpp_properties.json and launch.json. I don't know what to include in these files and am getting different errors while trying values from different sources for the aforementioned jsons. So, if you or anyone could provide the contents of the files, for an easy setup on Mac, it would be great.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, there are dozens of ways to build C++ projects, with several layers of tools. Without knowing uour build process it is impossible to help. If you can get compile output view (as text, copy-paste) from some of these, it probably would help a lot here.

Comment: @hyde, could you please tell me how to obtain info about my build process so that I can paste it here? I just remember installing xcode. I don't remember explicitly setting any build process for sublime, etc. Or rather, if the only 3 things I want from VS Code is 1) Intellisense code completion, 2) Ability to run a simple C++ file 3) Ability to debug a simple C++ file, what configurations should I mention in the config files above?

Comment: Your linker error hints at an options mismatch, are you compiler for x86, or other, and linking for x64? You look like you’ve got the build tools from homebrew, so it wouldn’t be obvious what the defaults that you have are.

Comment: @Niall Okay. How to find out what needs to be found out to set each of the properties in the required files correctly? I may have used homebrew, I don't remember and I have no clue what the settings are or how to find what they are so that I can set their values in the configuration files

Comment: Clang command line options are very similar to gcc. If I recall off hand `clang -v` will give echo the options being used with its current invocation. The easiest to diagnose this may well be to start with a clean workspace, adding a single file with a “hello world” code sample and build from there. Once working, add a second file and start comparing the working build with your failed build. The differences should start to show where the issues lie.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the error message from `ld` I think that the `tasks.json` causes the compiler/linker to pick up the wrong source file e.g. `ld` seems to process your `/Users/xyz/Workspace/VSCode/.vscode/tasks.json`.

Look at the description/example of tasks.json's variable `${file}` [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables-examples)

I think you have the `tasks.json` file *opened* and *focussed* in VSC when starting the debug session. `${file}` is therefore substituted with this opened `tasks.json` file. Please put the focus on your c/c++ *source file*, then start the debug session.

I did not closely examine the correctness of your configuration files since I use Apple's command line tools clang and lldb that come with Xcode. VSC did suggest and generated the correct default config files for this environment in my case. I'm use the C/C++ 0.24.0 extension from Microsoft. (I only had to add `"-std=c++11",` to the `args` in `tasks.json` to get clang recognise `c++11` source code).

Comment: This is correct answer, i faced the same issue, wasn't realising while i was building the task i has .json file opened.